# If I use random seed, will this guarantee that there will be a lot of repetition of gerated numbers?

Tags: python, random

I have a question about how Python's native random library generates pseudo-random numbers. Specifically about the repetitions of the generated numbers.

When using the random seed function from the random library, the pseudo random numbers generated on a scale from 0 to 1, if I call the function several times, will they repeat with a certain frequency?

If yes, would it be very frequent, to the point of becoming a memorable sequence? Or allow us to state that a given value between 0 and 1 would always appear several times in a range of executions?

If I use random seed, will this guarantee that there will be a lot of repetition of numbers?

Comment: See the python docs for [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). It has a period of 2**19937-1. (This number is 6002 digits long.) Yes, the generator does repeat. No, you're never going to live long enough to see those repeats. If you start with the same seed, you'll get the same sequence.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks. But then, if I always use the same seed, like you said I would get the same sequence, would I see repetitions frequently? Or even using a seed, would the results take a long time to be repeated?

Comment: Pseudo-random number generators mimic the mathematically well-established behaviors of independent uniformly distributed values. That means that having no duplicate values until you get a repeat of the entire sequence would be bad, but having too many duplicate individual values would also be bad. So within a sequence, you can see duplicates but they happen with probabilities corresponding to a generalization of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). However, if you use the same seed for two different sequences, the sequences will be identical.

Comment: A PRNG *always* has a seed, whether or not you explicitly set one (the default seed is typically something derived from the current time).  So there's not going to be any difference in behavior based on whether or not you provided a seed.